# delivery headers by ZuulFilter fail

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have overridden the `run()` method in a `ZuulFilter` as

```
RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
ctx.addZuulRequestHeader('header name', 'value');
```

However, in another service I can't find the header from the request.

More details, `filterType` is `"pre"` and there is only one filter.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail. What kind of filter is it (pre, route, post)? What order is it?

Comment: @spencergibb pre and only one filter order is 0

Answer (score 0):

Header added in a Zuul filter,

```
context.addZuulRequestHeader("my-header", "my-value");
```

can be retrieved in another filter this way,

```
context.getZuulRequestHeaders().get("my-header");
```

I also try to keep my pre-filter order low, e.g., -1000;

You can retrieve the header in an internal service, a client of Zuul, as you would do it for any other header. There is no **distinction** between regular request header and Zuul header, e.g.,

```
@RequestMapping(value = /abc/hello, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public MyObject read(@RequestHeader("my-header") String value) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: How can I getZuulRequestHeaders in Zuul clients?

Comment: Updated my posting with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Example filter adding a header:

```
public class AddHeaderFilter extends ZuulFilter {
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    public int filterOrder() {
        return 100;
    }

    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    public Object run() {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        context.addZuulRequestHeader('header name', "value");
        return null;
    }

}
```

Then in the application configuration you have to load the filter as a bean:

```
@Bean
AddHeaderFilter addHeaderFilter() {
    return new AddHeaderFilter();
}
```